# How did GeorgeNotFound use water on leaves without waterlogging it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

You know, placing water on leaves will make them waterlogged. But how GeorgeNotFound placed water on a tree [in Minecraft death swap video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXS1pXWslxs) without waterlogging it? Is it possible? If yes, how?

**Edit**

I've also seen placing water on leaves in [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=z2aKTX9LH18) video

Comment: Hi Matin, do they use mods? And can't you ask them?

Comment: actually, I don't think so they'll answer. But also I've seen it in https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=z2aKTX9LH18

Comment: Death Swap presumably is modded (although the same thing could probably be implemented with command blocked), but I doubt they would mod this oddly-specific feature.

Comment: @pppery Yeah, but it could be part of a mod or even a bug introduced by incompatibility.

Comment: the funny thing is that i've accidently waterlogged leaves in I think a 1.13 snapshot, but idk which snapshot, not do I have any footage of it, and see nothing online about this. Not even 100% sure I saw this, could have been a dream, but I'm quite certain this was possible

Comment: @Joachim it might be. But because I've seen this in several videos, I'm not pretty sure this is correct. I added another video link that I saw this in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

⁷The ability to waterlog leaves was added to Minecraft Java Edition in Version 1.19 snapshot 22w12a as per the [History section on the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Waterlogging#History). This released on 24 March 2022.

While I was unable to find the exact moment you describe in the Death Swap video, based on the description it is likely they are playing in version 1.14. There is a slim chance that it could be 1.15 based on the upload date. So leaves would not be waterlogged in either of these versions.

Note that this may not apply to Bedrock edition, which implements waterlogging differently.